# Accessing mutable properties in a timer event handler

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I want to provide read/write access to class property in side a timer's event handler but also update the same property elsewhere in the class outside the event handler. What precautions do I need to take to make sure that the correct data is being read & updated?

Here's the general logic:

```
// declared in the class header and initialized to 1 in init
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber           *sharedItem;
@property (nonatomic, assign) dispatch_source_t  timer;

// Method invoked independent of the timer
- (void)doSomeWork {
    // QUESTION: During a timer tick, will it access the correct version of 
    // sharedItem that is updated here? 
    // Do I need to protect this area with a critical section/lock?
    sharedItem = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[sharedItem intValue] + 1];
}

- (void)myTimerRelatedMethod {

    // Creating the timer
    _timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
    dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timer, startTime, interval, leeway);

    // Timer's event handler run for each tick
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.timer, ^{
        if ([sharedItem intValue] > 10) {
            // 1. Do something 
            // 2. Then cancel the timer
        }
    });

    dispatch_resume(self.timer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple primitives you can just set the property to atomic, and you dont have to worry about read write inconsistencies between threads.

For pointers you should use @synchronize to avoid read write consistencies in addition to setting the property to atomic.

Also note that if your timer is in the same thread as the rest of your code (on the main thread+runloop), you dont need to do anything, as the timer event will be fired by the same runloop firing in the rest of the main thread code, and will not be truly concurrent.

Comment: After re-reading the Apple doc, I think I understand that if I remove the nonatomic attribute from 'sharedItem', it should work fine. [..] specify strong, copy, or retain and do not specify nonatomic, then in a reference-counted environment, a synthesized get accessor for an object property uses a lock and retains and autoreleases the returned value. If you specify nonatomic, a synthesized accessor for an object property simply returns the value directly. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

Comment: Correct but that only protects a non pointer primitive type value, it does not protect the data contained in an object which is a pointed to by the property.  Thats why you need @synchronize when mutating the object from multiple threads.

Comment: I doubt dispatch_source is even running on a separate thread, so if you dont have other code running on other threads dont worry about it.

Comment: Got it. But isn't NSNumber a non-primitive type?

Comment: Yes it is non primitive although it gets some special handling to allow you to treat autobox values into and out of it.  However, its immutable - in which case setting the property to atomic is fine because you are never mutating the object itself you are just replacing it.

Comment: One more question - if I were to replace NSNumber with NSDate, would I then want to make the property strong/atomic and use @synchronize whenever the NSDate is changed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18345/discussion-between-stackmonster-and-howard-spear)